# How to parallelize a negamax algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, artificial-intelligence, negamax

Is there a way to parallelize the following negamax algorithm?

```
01 function negamax(node, depth, color)
02     if depth = 0 or node is a terminal node
03         return color * the heuristic value of node
04     bestValue := −∞
05     foreach child of node
06         v := −negamax(child, depth − 1, −color)
07         bestValue := max( bestValue, v )
08     return bestValue
```

Answer (score 0):

When formulated like that, as a single recursive function, not easily.

The easiest way would be to split it up into two functions: one specifically for your very first call at the root of the tree, and then a different function that is called and also recursively continues calling itself. In the root version, you could then parallelize the loop through children, and store the different values in a list. Then you'll just need a non-parallelized loop afterwards to find the max out of the list, but that'll be done instantly.

Note that, if you move on to enhancements like alpha-beta pruning, this will become much more complicated; naively parallelizing the first loop like I suggested here will significantly reduce the number of nodes that can be pruned by alpha-beta pruning

Answer (score 0):

### Topology + pure-[`[SERIAL]`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8337936/5) value-dependency chain decides a game:

Given the tree-topology, the use of a recursive formulation is not a cause, but rather a resulting causal-effect, as the recursion formulation is so simple to sketch and code. ( For those indeed interested in Computer Science, just benchmark the resources consumption of recursively-formulated computing strategies, and test ( in both the **`[SPACE]`**- and **`[TIME]`**-domains ) how soon it starts to create troubles, once your benchmark scaling grows a bit outside the school-book example problem scales and/or beyond designers' choice in this very resources-limiting dilemma on how deep recursion levels are fair to expect and set resources for and what happens next, if recursions try to dive a step deeper, than this "pre-wired" glass ceiling did happen ).

---

### How to convert this into a true-[**`[PARALLEL]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8337936/5) computing schedule?

A question about chances to find a true-[**`[PARALLEL]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8337936/5) processing strategy gets decided straight on finding a non-parallelisable pure-[**`[SERIAL]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8337936/5) dependency chains, which start from each of the terminal nodes and progress backwards, towards the tree root-node.

Tree topologies require some sort of "communication" of mutual-dependencies, that appear during the reversed traversing of the tree, so all the principal advantages a true-[**`[PARALLEL]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8337936/5) processing schedule may allow are efficiently lost in such a need to transfer products of pure-[`[SERIAL]`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8337936/5) value-dependency chains to the "next", non-local processing flow-of-code execution. This makes the original idea an anti-pattern.

Having realised this principally pure-[**`[SERIAL]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8337936/5) dependency, any wannabe-parallelisation enforcement attempts remain possible, but performance results thereof become more an anti-pattern, than any reasonably supported choice, as they will actually cost more ( in `[TIME]`-domain ), than a serial-chain processing ( being formulated recursively or not ), given the `[SPACE]`-domain permits such modus operandi.